# Using geometry column as primary key

Tags: postgis, postgresql

I have a PostgreSQL/PostGIS table which stores data about all the warning signs around the world. The map data is provided to me by our vendor, and the data is such that no possible combination of columns from the table can be used to define a suitable primary key for the table.

My objective is to create a primary key and creating a new AUTO_INCREMENT-like column with plain integers is not going to cut it.

Since the only column with actually unique data is the geometry column provided to me, is there any way to use this data in order to develop/create a suitable primary key?

Comment: Concatenate coordinates of the point, if this is a point.

Comment: you can get creative here: (first) points coordinate(s) (or centroid) or `ST_GeoHash`, `ST_AsGeoBuf` and so on. but, what's wrong with adding an integer identity column?

Comment: let me add, as a rule of thumb: a primary key should be as small as necessary (performance and size of its index) and its values should never change (e.g. via `UPDATE`)! I'd strongly suggest a (numeric) surrogate primary key.

Comment: This is great! Thank you for suggesting so many approaches to manipulate the geometry column @ThingumaBob. I read up on `ST_GeoHash()` and from what I understand it generates a hash that can be decoded and that is pretty darn useful!

Comment: A geohash does indeed create a hash, but, it's purpose isn't typically to create a primary key. And, depending on precision, you would get a lot of clashes, so, it would actually, be a pretty awful choice for a primary key.

Comment: Why can't you just use a SERIAL data type as a primary key? Not going to cut it is not very clear.

Comment: Hi @JohnPowell, thank you so much for taking the time to respond! So I was just wondering if there was a meaningful P.K that I could generate from the geometry column, and when I visualize the map in a tool, say QGIS, I would be able to make sense of the P.K. The reason probably seems silly I know, but I didn't want to go with a numeric P.K.

Comment: You can use the geometry itself as a primary key, it just isn't a very good idea. You still haven't stated why you can't just use SERIAL (integer) data type?

Comment: I can use the SERIAL data type. Consider this, I visualize my data via QGIS and when I hover over a record from the table and select it using the 'identify' tool I'd see a random integer in the P.K instead which adds no value, but a hash on the other hand has advantages like sorting and searching based on prefixes.

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't very clear explaining my reason for not wanting to use a SERIAL column.

Comment: btw., QGIS looks for columns having `id` in it's name that will be displayed in the *Identify* dialog, and if not present, chooses either the first column of the table that can be cast to text or leaves it blank. that has nothing to do with the primary key.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't say why a new auto increment column with plain integers will not "cut it" but a standard robust alternative to the unique ID problem is to use a [UUID](http://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-uuid/).  You can set this witha default too for new data imports.

If you want to use the geometry then you could go with John Powell's answer or altenatively, for point data, you could use a [geohash](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_GeoHash.html) (ST_geohash). A geohash can also be useful for clustering your data (though you can do that on the geometry directly).

However, you should bear in mind that geometry can't really be guaranteed to be unique unless you have first checked for the presence of duplicate geometries.  Even then, it may be perfectly legitimate to have two distinct features with identical geometry (depending on use-case) and you'd therefore want different primary keys. So I'd consider geometry to be a poor choice as a primary key for these reasons and personally opt for UUID.

Comment: Why would you prefer a UUID over a SERIAL type? It is larger, and unless you are concerned about global, as distinct from within you table, uniqueness, it seems like overkill.

Comment: You misunderstand - I would prefer a UUID over geometry as a primary key.  If a serial type won't 'cut it' as the OP says (presumably because this is a distributed system and serial is only unique in a given database) then UUID gives "better uniqueness" guaranteed between the DBs in the system.  If this is not a distributed system then serial is absolutely fine IMO.  But the OP believes that serial is not enough... which leaves UUID

Comment: Fair enough. Yes, it would be helpful if the OP stated what "won't cut it" means. It is quite possible to use SERIAL in a distributed system, using increments of more than 1, and different starting points, but it is somewhat fiddly, and in that context, a UUID would be better, agreed.

Comment: To be clear, I think using geometry as a primary key is a pretty bad idea, I was just pointing out that you could.

Answer (score 3):

You can actually create a primary key directly on a geometry column. It had never actually occurred to me to do this, and it seems unnatural compared to either an arbitrary number, ie, a [serial data type](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-numeric.html#DATATYPE-SERIAL), or some meaningful attribute or unique combination of attributes of the geometry's properties. As you will almost certainly want a spatial index also, you will end up with two different types of index on the same column, which is wasteful of space, as a serial data type is smaller than a geometry, and guaranteed to be unique.

It is also perfectly reasonable to have the same geometry, but with different attributes, eg, point samples over time. You would be unable to support this with a spatial column as a primary key.

Here is a small example, using a random number generator to create a million points, and the DISTINCT keyword to ensure they are unique (which is extremely likely, but not certain).

```
CREATE TABLE spatial_primary (geom geometry);
INSERT INTO spatial_primary (geom) 
 (SELECT DISTINCT ST_Makepoint(random(), random()) 
         FROM generate_series(1, 1000000));
```

Create both a primary key on the geometry column and a spatial index.

```
ALTER TABLE spatial_primary ADD PRIMARY KEY (geom);
CREATE INDEX ix_spatial_primary ON spatial_primary USING GIST (geom);
```

Now, attempt to insert a duplicate:

```
INSERT INTO spatial_primary SELECT geom FROM spatial_primary LIMIT 1;
```

> ERROR:  duplicate key value violates unique constraint "spatial_primary_pkey"
>   DETAIL:  Key (geom)=(0101000000000000C9FA9BEB3F0000008BB9F1D63F) already exists.

So, while it is unusual and probably not best practice, nothing prevents you from creating a primary key on a geometry, so long as the geometries are unique. However, it is almost certainly better to use some other unique value, whether serial, UUID (as MappaGnosis suggests) or some attribute(s) of the geometry.

Comment: Valuable input on here John! I appreciate you taking the time. :) I'll be implementing your approach on a dummy database. I was just checking the prod db and turns out there are some duplicate geometries too. :/

Comment: To be clear, I don't think you should use this approach :-). I was just saying you could. SERIAL is by far the best approach if you need to add a primary key or, if you have a distributed system, a UUID, as MappaGnosis suggests.